Question about inequality
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite simple graph and $d_{u_i}$ is the degree of vertex $u_i$ in $G$.
Note:
For every integer $\alpha\geq 1$, $(1+x)^{\alpha}\geq1+\alpha x$.
Let $x=d_{u_i} -1$, then according to above note
$$(1+d_{u_i}-1)^2\geq 1+2(d_{u_i}-1)\Rightarrow d_{u_i}^{2}\geq 2d_{v_i} -1,$$
$$(1+d_{v_i}-1)^2\geq 1+2(d_{v_i} -1)\Rightarrow d_{v_i}^{2}\geq 2d_{u_i} -1,$$
then $ d_{u_i}^2 +d_{v_i}^{2}\geq 2d_{u_i} +2d_{v_i}-2$.
Is it right to say?

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{ d_{u_i}^2 +d_{v_i}^{2}}\geq \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{2d_{u_i} +2d_{v_i}-2}$$

Can the right side of the inequality ($\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{2d_{u_i} +2d_{v_i}-2}$) be simplified?

$‎‎(1+d_{u_i}-1)^2‎\geq 1+2(d_{u_i}-1)‎\Rightarrow d_{u_i}‎^{2}‎\geq 2d_{v_i} -2‎‎‎‎$ it should end with $...-1$, not $....-2$

Could you give a more informative title? \ In terms of "continu[ing] the proof", what are you proving? \ Like your other current front-page question, this one had lots of invisible occurrences of left-to-right marks, and a right-to-left mark.  I removed them.
